# 2-column layout with footer and absolutely positioned, 100% height right column

Tags: html, css

I have a simple two column layout:

```
<div class = "parent">
   <div class = "left-column">
   </div>
   <div class = "right-column">
   </div>
</div>
<div class = "footer"></div>
```

The content within each column is dynamic, and thus the height of each column cannot be predicted in advance.  However, I have a requirement that the RIGHT column has a background color that ALWAYS extends to the bottom of the page, even if the right column is much shorter than the left.

To accomplish this, I gave "parent" `position:relative`, and "right-column" has:

```
.right-column {
   position:absolute; 
   height: 100%; 
   right: 0px; 
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Full JSFiddle link: **http://jsfiddle.net/gsmbzaz9/1/**

So, of course, there's many issues here.

Firstly, it seems that when I say `height: 100%` of the `<body>` or `<html>` element, that means the *screen* height (not the page height), so when I position the footer with `bottom: 0` relative to `body`, it moves the footer to the bottom of the *screen* - *not* the bottom of the page.

That would be fine if I wanted to use `position: fixed` with the footer, so that the footer was always visible as you scroll.  But here I want the footer to *only* be visible if you scroll all the way to the bottom.

Secondly, the right column is TALLER than the left in this example.  So the content spills over beyond the bottom of the `parent` div, and worse, the blue background is clipped.

So, ultimately I'm looking for this layout to render as follows:

```
+------+-------+
|      |       |
| LEFT | RIGHT |
|      |       |
+------+       |
       |       |
       |       |
+--------------+
|    FOOTER    |
+--------------+
```

...where the entire right column is blue.  We also may have a situation wherein LEFT is taller than RIGHT, in which case the blue background behind RIGHT will be fine, but the LEFT column content spills over the footer.

This seems like a pretty common layout - I'm surprised how much difficulty I've had.  I've googled around trying to learn about various techniques for positioning a footer div at the bottom of the page, but none of the techniques I've seen deal with the case when there is an absolutely positioned column that lies outside the flow of the document.

So, what are some techniques using CSS to achieve the specified layout, taking into account the requirement thats:

1. The exact height of the left and right columns cannot be known (due to dynamic content)
2. The RIGHT column must always have a background color that extends to the bottom footer
3. The footer stays firmly planted at the *bottom* of the page (page, *not* screen) and is only visible when you scroll down to the bottom (or if the content is small enough that there are no scrollbars)

Comment: Please pare this question down - it's difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: footer has fixed height always?

Comment: @Danko, yes the footer height can be fixed

Comment: @Siler - http://jsfiddle.net/ysfeuzL3/   is this what you were looking to achieve?

Comment: @Sai, close except in that example the footer won't necessary always appear at the exact bottom of the page if for example there is very little content in left and right columns

Comment: First,  height 100% may not be what you are looking for,  it only is 100% of the viewport not the document.  Also the absolute positioning means the element is taken out of the document flow.  I suggest looking into using floats with clears, or if you can use more updated method, inline-blocks.

Comment: @Siler--  an updated fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/ysfeuzL3/3/  used javascript to dynamically find the heights. let me know if this is something you were looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is One way to do this, the important properties I've used are:

> box-sizing:border-box -------- padding ----- display:table-cell ----position:relative for footer --

#### First Snippet With Few Content

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
#cont {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  position: relative;
  top: -70px;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: red;
}
.left-column > div {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
.right-column {
  background: orange;
}
.left-column,
.right-column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="left-column">
    <div>
      <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

#### Second Snippet With More Content With Scrollbars

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
#cont {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  position: relative;
  top: -70px;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: red;
}
.left-column > div {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
.right-column {
  background: orange;
}
.left-column,
.right-column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="left-column">
    <div>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Tables to the rescue.  (Just kidding, it's not *really* tables)

Comment: @Siler I know maybe someone doesn't like the display table but it's the only way I found to acomplish all your requirements....With Flexbox also can be an option but the compatibility can be an issue

Comment: no I think your solution is great.  I really don't understand the argument against `display:table` - it doesn't have any of the drawbacks of the old `<table>` layouts, because you can use media queries on the CSS to support responsive design, and the layout isn't as cluttered with all the `<tr><td>` etc.

Answer (score 3):

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ysfeuzL3/3/

I used a little javascript for the solution.

Now as per your requirement the 2 columns are properly aligned with the footer always at the bottom of the divs ( not the window) and also the right column is always extending to the full height to the footer.

Hope this helps

Code snippet....

```js
function heightAdjust() {
  lHeight = $(".left-column").outerHeight();
  rHeight = $(".right-column").outerHeight();
  if (lHeight >= rHeight) {
    $(".right-column").outerHeight(lHeight);
  }
}

heightAdjust()

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  heightAdjust()
})

$(window).on('load', function() {
  heightAdjust()
})
```

```css
  h1 {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .left-column {
    float: left;
    background: red
  }
  .right-column {
    float: right;
    background: blue;
  }
  .clearfix {
    clear: both;
  }
  .footer {
    background: aqua;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="left-column">
      <h1>Content</h1>

      <br/>
      <h1>Content</h1>

      <br/>
      <h1>Content</h1>

      <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <!-- remove these to see the height adjust -->
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <h1>right</h1>
      <br/>
      <!-- remove these to see the height adjust -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h1>FOOTER</h1>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sai - this solution meets all the requirements.  I'm pretty surprised it's non-trivial (or not possible?) to get a CSS only solution to these requirements.  If nobody comes up with a CSS only solution, I'll go with this solution

Comment: @Siler--  the problem with CSS only solution is that you need to dynamically set the height of the right column in accordance to the left column height... which CSS only solution will fail. sorry

Comment: This solution doesnt account for the case if there is no content in either column. http://jsfiddle.net/ysfeuzL3/4/, however this solution does: http://fiddle.jshell.net/kr5tbgm6/5/

Comment: @GraceLee - if there were no content in either column, still there is nothing to show and also the right column will still extend to the footer.

Comment: @Sai yes, it will extend to the footer, but not the height of the page

Answer (score 1):

jquery is used in this solution. heres the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/kr5tbgm6/5/).  It accounts for the following requirements:

-the right column needs to extend to the bottom of the scrollable page regardless if it has more content or less content than the left column

-no absolutes

-footer is on the bottom of the page

-the min height of the right column reaches to the bottom of the window

css:

```
h1 {
    padding: 20px;
}
.left-column {
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
    /* background-color: blue; */
}
.right-column {
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    float: right;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.footer {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    /* background-color: yellow; */
}
```

jquery:

```
var leftHeight = $('.left-column').height();
var rightHeight = $('.right-column').height();
var windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
var footerHeight = $('.footer').height();

console.log(leftHeight, rightHeight, windowHeight);

if(leftHeight > windowHeight && leftHeight > rightHeight) {
    $('.right-column').height(leftHeight);
}
if(windowHeight > leftHeight && windowHeight > rightHeight) {
    $('.right-column').height(windowHeight - footerHeight);
}
```

Comment: @Danko I added the windowHeight to account for that. [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/kr5tbgm6/4/)