# change height depending on other div on window resize

Tags: jquery, css, resize

I have two 50% width div's next to each other.
One of the two has more text in it and makes the div longer then the other one.
I have a javascript that makes the other div the same height even though it has less text.
That works great, even when I resize the window to a smaller window (tablet size) both div's change in height but stay the same. But the problem is when I change the window back to the normal size; the div heights stay the same height as happened after the resize but don't change back to the state they were before the window resize.

**This is the JS that changes height on window resize:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function block() {
var leftHeight = $('.leftblock').height();
var rightHeight = $('.rightblock').height();
if (leftHeight > rightHeight){ $('.rightblock').css('height', leftHeight); }
else{ $('.leftblock').css('height', rightHeight); }
}
$(block);
$(window).resize(block);
});
```

**example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/hg0L01ex/

Comment: here is an answer to a problem that is similar to yours that adjusts on resize as well.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533818/2-column-layout-with-footer-and-absolutely-positioned-100-height-right-column/27534240#27534240

Comment: Thank you Sai for your answer but that topic has the same solution as I have but has a window-resize error too: http://jsfiddle.net/ysfeuzL3/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Added by Erwin van Ekeren:*
**The (best) solution for my problem is working without JS but with CSS table-cells**: http://jsfiddle.net/2uogqxyt

---

Don't use JavaScript for that but CSS. Either the [FlexBox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) model or table-cells;

Here it is with table-cell :

```
.blocks { display:table-row;}
.leftblock          { display:table-cell; width:50%; padding:100px 0 100px 0; margin:0; background:#e14f47; }
.rightblock         { display:table-cell; width:50%; padding:100px 0 100px 0; margin:0; background:#cd2c24; }
```

[Demonstration with table-cell](http://jsfiddle.net/ajhyjv7n/)

```
.blocks { display:flex; width:100%; align-items:stretch;}
.leftblock          { flex-grow:1; padding:100px 0 100px 0; margin:0; background:#e14f47; }
.rightblock         { flex-grow:1; padding:100px 0 100px 0; margin:0; background:#cd2c24; }
```

[Demonstration with flexbox](http://jsfiddle.net/g6pgb2pu/)

Comment: the table-cell solution works great but somehow it takes the width of the div inside and nog the 50% of the parent 100% div. Flex is totally new for me, I need to find out how that works cause in your example both divs are above eachother instead of next to eachother

Comment: above each other ? In my demo ?

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren Regarding the table solution, is that what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/2uogqxyt/